# Why is my PHP date_diff not working properly?

Tags: php

I have this messaging system, and I my plan is to store all the messages under New York time then convert them to the users timezone using some javascript (to find their timezone). So I take the users current time based on their timezone, then take the current time in new york, then I add or subtract this time from the message time to convert it. But for some reason, my date_diff isn't working. Here is my code:

```
$dateofmessage = date_create($message['date_time']);
date_default_timezone_set("{$_GET['userTimezone']}");
$date1 = date_create(date("y-m-d H:i:s"));
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date2 = date_create(date("y-m-d H:i:s"));
if ($date1 > $date2) {
    $diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
    $differenceToAddOrSub = $diff->format("%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds");
    $changeddate = date_create(date_add($dateofmessage, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$differenceToAddOrSub")));
} elseif ($date2 > $date1) {
    $diff = date_diff($date2, $date1);
    $differenceToAddOrSub = $diff->format("%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds");
    $changeddate = date_create(date_sub($dateofmessage, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$differenceToAddOrSub")));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? What do you expect and what are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that `$date1` and `$date2` is producing output as expected. The `date` function depends on the time configuration of the server. Make sure that the timezone of the server is correct. You may check this by using `date` in SSH.

The `date_create` accepts date in format: `date('Y-m-d')`, not `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`. The latter format causes unpredictable results.

```
$date1 = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
```

Comment: You are right, it is not outputting anything, I even put : 
```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```
And it outputted the correct thing, but when I tried to date_create($date1) It didn't work, it doesn't echo any error message though. What's the problem.

Comment: I have updated the answer above. Please use date('Y-m-d') only. Note the capital 'Y'. Keep in mind that if the user is in the same timezone, this returns no difference.